# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. parameter name index. thrown by ObservableCollection.Add() method

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, observablecollection

So in my application i have a need to display some images For that i used `ItemsControl` and `UniformGrid` data bound to `ObservableCollection<Image>`
like this

```
<ItemsControl Name="ImageItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableCollectionSource}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <UniformGrid Rows="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        </UniformGrid>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
```

It works just fine, when i just start the program,
But then at some point, i need to unload all the images from the grid.
Because if i call `.Clear()` on my collection it breaks my binding, just remove all the elements one by one like this:

```
int limit = ObservableCollectionSource.Count -1;
                for (int i = limit; i >= 0; i--)
               {
                    ObservableCollectionSource.RemoveAt(i);
               }
```

At first glance it seems to work correctly, but then when i need to add images back to the grid(by drag and drop, or from open file dialog - result is the same).
It throws this exception

> specified argument was out of the range of valid values. parameter
>   name index

At the line where i call `.Add()` method.

```
Image img = CreateImage(cImg);
                    try
                    {
                       ObservableCollectionSource.Add(img);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex )
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Exception has occured: " + ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                    }
```

Here i create wpf image with necessary "settings" from the bitmap that I loaded from file, And try to add it to my ObservableCollection.

Any ideas why it doesn't work, or directions for me to do research about?

Googling around didn't produce any results(maybe i just formulated my search queries poorly), and i'm all out of ideas.

Do I bind it wrong? Do I use wrong controls for the task?

I don't know.

Any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT: Here is Stack Trace from the Exception that i get

```
at System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.Insert(Int32 index, Visual visual)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.AddChildren(GeneratorPosition pos, Int32 itemCount)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.OnItemsChangedInternal(Object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.OnItemsChanged(Object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.OnItemAdded(Object item, Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList`1.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, Type managerType)
   at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.OnViewCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList`1.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, Type managerType)
   at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChangedWithAdjustedIndex(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args, Int32 adjustedOldIndex, Int32 adjustedNewIndex)
   at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
   at MainDesk.MainWindow.AddImagesToGrid() in D:\MainDesk\MainDesk\UI\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 427
   at MainDesk.MainWindow.AddCarrierImageBtn_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in D:\MainDesk\MainDesk\UI\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 167
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at MainDesk.App.Main() in D:\MainDesk\MainDesk\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: I must've missed that part. Does your program involve multiple threads that could be accessing the collection at once?

Comment: No, not on my part. It's a simple "exercise" wpf app, where i display user loaded images. And can load, and unload them all at once, or one by one.

Comment: Unless `ObservableCollection<T>` is broken in a bizarre way, which is unlikely, that's still the only explanation I can think of. I.e. something has corrupted the internal state of the collection, and that usually only happens with bad concurrency. You're sure you're not spawning any extra threads with things such as `Task.Run` or friends either?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen 
I'm pretty sure. I don't use any multi threading in this program whatsoever.
Is it the only thing that could've caused it?

Comment: That's the most likely explanation. Of course it could also be caused by a bug in `ObservableCollection` itself, but that's something used by countless people countless times every day, so it's unlikely to have bugs that you could easily run into. At any rate calling `Add` on a collection should not be able to throw that exception.

Comment: Actually now that I think of it - did you look closely at the stack trace in the exception? Was the exception propagated through from an event handler or something that `Add` might have called to notify about changes? What's the top few methods in the stack trace?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen
I'm not overly familiar with how to do that. So i'd look into it, and then edit my question if i find something unusual.

Thank you for your advice

Comment: If you debug your program and get VS to break when the exception occurs, you should be able to go into the exception details and look at it.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Yeah, i've done that already, and added Stack Trace from the exception to the question. My problem is - i have no idea what any of that means.

Comment: Problem did not reproduce: I can remove all items, one-by-one, in a loop, or calling `Clear()` and then add it back with no exceptions. BTW calling `Clear()` does not break any bindings either. The problem must be "somewhere else" you're not showing us.

Comment: I cannot figure out where. Anyway, posting my entire project here is of no use. It's not like anyone got time to look into it. So i guess question may be closed. In the meantime, i'd try to rewrite this part from scratch, and maybe along the way i'll figure out what i was doing wrong. Thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: Post where and how you're creating your `ViewModel` and assigning it to your `DataContext`.

Comment: @jstreet It seems that i've got rid of a problem, though i still have no understanding of what exactly was a cause of such behaviour.
I apologize for not posting enough relevant info. Clearly i didn't understand my own question. 

I've posted an answer below, with explanation of what seemed to be causing my problem. If you can take a look, and maybe explain me why it was working that way, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Michael as long as the problem is gone, it's all that matters. Next time remember to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so you can get meaningful help.

Comment: @jstreet Will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

So it seems I figured out where my mistake was.

First of all. About `.Clear()` breaking my binding. - I completely forgot about `NotifyPropertyChanged`. However, when i got this part figured out, the exception persisted.

Now to the main part - I overestimated, the simplicity of my application, and as a result didn't post enough relevant info. 
After i was unable to reproduce the problem in a smaller app, that had nothing in it but one `ObservableCollection` and one `ItemsPanel` with `UniformGrid` in it. I knew the problem is somewhere else.

So it turns out, that i for some reason, at the same time i was adding the `Image`s to the `ObservableCollection` in question, i was also adding this images to another `ObservableCollection` which was `ItemsSource` for another `ItemsPanel`. Two panels are identical, but have no knowledge of each other, and are not connected in any way.

Thing is, one of them was had it's `Visibility` as `Visibility.Collapsed` when i was adding items to it's `ObservableCollection`.

Now, when i only work with one `ObservalbeCollection` at a time - problem is gone.

Though i still have no idea what was the cause of such behavior.

Comment: I am having the same issue, same `ObservableCollection` is bound to two `ItemSource`s and if one of them is `IsEnabled=false` when adding elements I get the same `NullReferenceException`. It would be nice to know why it throws in this case :(